# (Java) Trying to number printed items in an if statement

Tags: java, arrays, list

So, I have an if statement inside of a for loop. The idea is, if the time difference between the current time and an updated time is greater  than 24 hours (or 86400000 milliseconds), then I print out the claim number.

This what my if statement looks like:

```
   if(difference>86400000){                 
        System.out.println(singleClaim.getString("claimNumber"));
            }
```

and this is what my output looks like (a list of claim numbers):

```
032394115-01
032398720-01
032395941-01
032398165-01
032395262-01
032395350-01
032392831-01
```

Since I have a lot of claim numbers that are being printed out, I was hoping to number them to make the list a bit easier to read.

Kind of like this:

```
1.) 032394115-01
2.) 032398720-01
3.) 032395941-01
4.) 032398165-01
5.) 032395262-01
6.) 032395350-01
7.) 032392831-01
```

Hopefully more experienced programmers than myself will find this fairly easy.

**EDIT:** I've been told that it would be helpful to show the entire for loop, so here it is below:

```
 for(ParseObject singleClaim : resultsList){
        //If the customerStatus is 5, we check to see if the updatedTime            is within 24 Hours.                 
    if(singleClaim.getInt("customerStatus") == 5) {
        //Create a date formatter.
        SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'");
        //Create a date object for today's date.
        Date currentDate=new Date();
        //Create a string for the date from parse.
        String parseTime = singleClaim.getString("updatedAt");            
        //Initialize the date object for the updatedAt time on Parse.
        Date parseDate = null;
        try {
        //Here, we convert the parseTime string into a date object and format it.
            parseDate = formatter.parse(parseTime);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        //Get the time difference from the current date versus the date on Parse in milliseconds.
        long difference = currentDate.getTime() - parseDate.getTime();


        for(int i=1;;i++ ){
        //If the time difference is more than 24 hours in milliseconds, we print out the claim number.
        if(difference>86400000){                    
        System.out.println(i + ".)" + singleClaim.getString("claimNumber"));
            }     
        else {       
        break;};
        }
        }}
        System.out.println("\n////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
        System.out.println("Done getting claims with customerStatus of 5 updated over 24 hours ago.");
        System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }}}
```

Comment: Along the lines of 'easier to read', but regarding your source code: Extract a method to make your if condition understandable for human beings: `if (claimIsOlderThen24Hours(difference)) { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a counter :

```
if(difference>86400000) {                 
    System.out.println(counter++ + ".)" + singleClaim.getString("claimNumber"));
}
```

Initialize the counter prior to your loop :

```
int counter = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I too recommend an `int counter = 1;`, but I would suggest formatted output with [`printf(String, Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). Something like

```
System.out.printf("%d.) %s%n", counter++, singleClaim.getString("claimNumber"));
```